# Accessing a changed DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a way to access a JS changed DOM element? I have an image box that changes based on changing the thumbnail using JS/JQ.

I have a second javascript which is a loupe that magnifies the image. However it is only magnifying the original src link, the original src inside the div, and not the changed src link.

In the debugger I can see the image change in div element but the loupe script cannot see it. It seems the loupe script is just accessing the original src of the div element.

Both JS/JQ scripts were written by different people and I'm trying to get them to work nicely together.

I'm new to JS so I'm not sure if this is possible.

Here is the HTML that is being changed (the gallery JS changes the src element):

```
 <img class="picture-slides-image"  src="artifactImages/bowl_fragment_16134_04E.jpg" alt=""/ >
```

Here is the JS in the HTML that sets the loupe going:

```
                <script>
                 $('.picture-slides-image').ClassyLoupe({
                    maxSize: 600,
                    size: 300,
                    minSize: 200,
                    loupeToggleSpeed: 'fast'
                 });
                </script>
```

Here is the JS for the loupe:

```
(function($) {
    var id = 0;
    jQuery.fn.ClassyLoupe = function(a) {
        id++;
        if (this.length > 1) {
            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).ClassyLoupe(a);
            }), this;
        }
        var a = $.extend({
            trigger: 'mouseenter',
            shape: 'circle',
            roundedCorners: 10,
            loupeToggleSpeed: 'medium',
            loupeToggleEasing: 'linear',
            size: 200,
            minSize: 150,
            maxSize: 250,
            glossy: true,
            shadow: true,
            resize: true,
            sizeSnap: 10,
            resizeAnimationSpeed: 'medium',
            resizeAnimationEasing: 'easeOutBack',
            canZoom: true,
            zoomKey: 90,
            zoom: 100,
            minZoom: 50,
            maxZoom: 200,
            zoomSnap: 5,
            zoomAnimationSpeed: 'medium',
            zoomAnimationEasing: 'easeOutBack',
            overlay: true,
            overlayOpacity: 0.5,
            overlayEffectSpeed: 'slow',
            overlayEffectEasing: 'easeOutBack',
            overlayClassName: ''
        }, a || {}), j = jQuery(this), c = 'classyloupe-' + id, t = 'classyloupe_overlay-' + id, h = a.size, i, q = null, u = 0, v = 0, x = 0, y = 0, r = 0, s = 0, w = false, p = false, k = a.zoom, n = 0, o = 0, e, z = false;
        return this.each(function() {
            function A() {
                var d = h - 2 * $('#' + c + ' .lglossy').css('marginTop'), e = h / 2, g = 0, f = 0;
                a.shape === 'circle' ? f = g = e : a.shape === 'rounded' && (g = parseInt($('#' + c).css('border-top-width')), f = g = a.roundedCorners - g);
                $('#' + c + ' .glossy').stop().animate({
                    width: d + 'px',
                    height: e + 'px',
                    '-webkit-border-top-left-radius': g + 'px',
                    '-webkit-border-top-right-radius': f + 'px',
                    '-moz-border-radius-topleft': g + 'px',
                    '-moz-border-radius-topright': f + 'px',
                    'border-top-left-radius': g + 'px',
                    'border-top-right-radius': f + 'px'
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    easing: a.resizeAnimationEasing,
                    duration: a.resizeAnimationSpeed
                });
            }
            function B(d, e) {
                if (w && a.canZoom) {
                    if (!(k + a.zoomSnap * d > a.maxZoom || k + a.zoomSnap * d < a.minZoom)) {
                        k += a.zoomSnap * d;
                        r += Math.round(x * a.zoomSnap / 100) * d;
                        s += Math.round(y * a.zoomSnap / 100) * d;
                        var g = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                        n = Math.round(r / u * (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft)) * -1 + h / 2;
                        o = Math.round(s / v * g) * -1 + h / 2;
                        $('#' + c).animate({
                            'background-position': n + 'px ' + o + 'px',
                            'background-size': r + 'px ' + s + 'px'
                        }, {
                            queue: false,
                            easing: a.zoomAnimationEasing,
                            duration: a.zoomAnimationSpeed,
                            complete: function() {
                                i = $('#' + c).outerWidth();
                                var a = new jQuery.Event('mousemove', {
                                    pageX: m + i / 2,
                                    pageY: l + i / 2
                                });
                                j.trigger(a);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                else if (a.resize && !w && (g = d * a.sizeSnap, !(h + g > a.maxSize || h + g < a.minSize))) {
                    h += g;
                    var f = 0, m = Math.round($('#' + c).offset().left - g), l = Math.round($('#' + c).offset().top - g);
                    n += g;
                    o += g;
                    $('#' + c).stop();
                    a.shape === 'circle' ? (f = h / 2, $('#' + c).animate({
                        width: h + 'px',
                        height: h + 'px',
                        '-webkit-border-top-left-radius': f + 'px',
                        '-webkit-border-top-right-radius': f + 'px',
                        '-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius': f + 'px',
                        '-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius': f + 'px',
                        '-moz-border-radius-topleft': f + 'px',
                        '-moz-border-radius-topright': f + 'px',
                        '-moz-border-radius-bottomleft': f + 'px',
                        '-moz-border-radius-bottomright': f + 'px',
                        'border-top-left-radius': f + 'px',
                        'border-top-right-radius': f + 'px',
                        'border-bottom-left-radius': f + 'px',
                        'border-bottom-right-radius': f + 'px',
                        'background-position': n + 'px ' + o + 'px',
                        left: m + 'px',
                        top: l + 'px'
                    }, {
                        queue: false,
                        easing: a.resizeAnimationEasing,
                        duration: a.resizeAnimationSpeed,
                        complete: function() {
                            i = $('#' + c).outerWidth();
                            var a = new jQuery.Event('mousemove', {
                                pageX: m + i / 2,
                                pageY: l + i / 2
                            });
                            j.trigger(a);
                        }
                    })) : a.shape === 'rounded' ? $('#' + c).animate({
                        width: h + 'px',
                        height: h + 'px',
                        '-webkit-border-radius': a.roundedCorners,
                        '-moz-border-radius': a.roundedCorners,
                        'border-radius': a.roundedCorners,
                        'background-position': n + 'px ' + o + 'px',
                        left: m + 'px',
                        top: l + 'px'
                    }, {
                        queue: false,
                        easing: a.resizeAnimationEasing,
                        duration: a.resizeAnimationSpeed,
                        complete: function() {
                            i = $('#' + c).outerWidth();
                            var a = new jQuery.Event('mousemove', {
                                pageX: m + i / 2,
                                pageY: l + i / 2
                            });
                            j.trigger(a);
                        }
                    }) : a.shape === 'square' && $('#' + c).animate({
                        width: h + 'px',
                        height: h + 'px',
                        'background-position': n + 'px ' + o + 'px',
                        left: m + 'px',
                        top: l + 'px'
                    }, {
                        queue: false,
                        easing: a.resizeAnimationEasing,
                        duration: a.resizeAnimationSpeed,
                        complete: function() {
                            i = $('#' + c).outerWidth();
                            var a = new jQuery.Event('mousemove', {
                                pageX: m + i / 2,
                                pageY: l + i / 2
                            });
                            j.trigger(a);
                        }
                    });
                    a.glossy && A();
                }
            }
            (function() {
                j.is("a") ? (q = j.attr('href'), e = j.find('img')) : (j.is('img') || j.is('input[type="image"]')) && (q = j.attr('src'), e = j);
                u = e.width();
                v = e.height();
                $('body').append('<div class="classyloupe" id="' + c + '"></div>');
                var d = new Image;
                d.onload = function() {
                    x = this.width;
                    y = this.height;
                    r = Math.round(x * k / 100);
                    s = Math.round(y * k / 100);
                    var d = h / 2;
                    $('#' + c).css({
                        width: h + 'px',
                        height: h + 'px',
                        'background-image': 'url(' + q + ')',
                        'background-size': r + 'px ' + s + 'px'
                    });
                    a.shape === 'circle' ? $('#' + c).css({
                        '-webkit-border-radius': d + 'px',
                        '-moz-border-radius': d + 'px',
                        'border-radius': d + 'px'
                    }) : a.shape === 'rounded' && $('#' + c).css({
                        '-webkit-border-radius': a.roundedCorners,
                        '-moz-border-radius': a.roundedCorners,
                        'border-radius': a.roundedCorners + 'px'
                    });
                    i = $('#' + c).outerWidth();
                    a.glossy && $('#' + c).append('<div class="lglossy"></div>');
                    a.overlay && ($('body').append("<div class='loverlay " + a.overlayClassName + "' id='" + t + "'></div>"), $('#' + t).css({
                        top: e.offset().top + 'px',
                        left: e.offset().left + 'px',
                        width: e.outerWidth() + 'px',
                        height: e.outerHeight() + 'px'
                    }));
                    a.shadow && $('#' + c).addClass('lshadow');
                };
                d.src = q;
            }(), (a.resize || a.canZoom) && !z && $.event.special.mousewheel && $('#' + c).bind('mousewheel', function(a, b) {
                B(b, a);
                return false;
            }), e.bind(a.trigger, function(d) {
                p ? ($('#' + c).fadeOut(a.loupeToggleSpeed, a.loupeToggleEasing), p = false, a.overlay && $('#' + t).fadeOut(a.overlayEffectSpeed, a.overlayEffectEasing)) : ($('#' + c).fadeIn(a.loupeToggleSpeed, a.loupeToggleEasing), p = true, a.overlay && $('#' + t).fadeTo(a.overlayEffectSpeed, a.overlayOpacity, a.overlayEffectEasing), A());
                if (d.type === 'click') {
                    return d.preventDefault ? d.preventDefault() : d.returnValue = false, false;
                }
            }), $('#' + c).bind('click', function() {
                e.trigger('click');
            }), $(document).bind('mousemove', function(d) {
                if (!p) {
                    return true;
                }
                var j = parseInt(e.css('border-left-width')) + parseInt(e.css('padding-left')),
                        g = parseInt(e.css('border-top-width')) + parseInt(e.css('padding-top')),
                        f = parseInt(e.css('border-right-width')) + parseInt(e.css('padding-right')),
                        m = parseInt(e.css('border-bottom-width')) + parseInt(e.css('padding-bottom')),
                        l = d.pageX - e.offset().left - j,
                        k = d.pageY - e.offset().top - g,
                        q = Math.round(d.pageX - i / 2),
                        d = Math.round(d.pageY - i / 2);
                n = Math.round(r / u * l) * -1 + h / 2;
                o = Math.round(s / v * k) * -1 + h / 2;
                $('#' + c).css({
                    'background-position': n + 'px ' + o + 'px'
                });
                $('#' + c).css({
                    left: q + 'px',
                    top: d + 'px'
                });
                if (l < -j || k < -g || l > u + f || k > v + m) {
                    $('#' + c).fadeOut(a.loupeToggleSpeed), p = false, a.overlay && $('#' + t).fadeOut(a.overlayEffectSpeed);
                }
            }), $(document).keyup(function(event) {
                if (event.which == a.zoomKey && p) {
                    return w = false, event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false, false;
                }
            }).keydown(function(event) {
                if (event.which == a.zoomKey && p) {
                    return w = true, event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false, false;
                }
            }));
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the JS for the gallery:

```
jQuery.PictureSlides = function () {
    var useMSFilter = false,
        slideshows = [],
        set = function (settings) {
            slideshows.push(settings);
        },

        init = function () {
            var counter = 0;
            $(".picture-slides-container").each(function () {
                var elm = $(this),

                    // Element references
                    settings = slideshows[counter++],
                    mainImage = elm.find("." + settings.mainImageClass),
                    mainImageFailedToLoad = elm.find("." + settings.mainImageFailedToLoadClass),
                    imageLink = elm.find("." + settings.imageLinkClass),
                    fadeContainer = elm.find("." + settings.fadeContainerClass),
                    imageTextContainer = elm.find("." + settings.imageTextContainerClass),
                    previousLink = elm.find("." + settings.previousLinkClass),
                    nextLink = elm.find("." + settings.nextLinkClass),
                    imageCounter = elm.find("." + settings.imageCounterClass),
                    startSlideShowLink = elm.find("." + settings.startSlideShowClass),
                    stopSlideShowLink = elm.find("." + settings.stopSlideShowClass),
                    thumbnailContainer = elm.find("." + settings.thumbnailContainerClass),
                    thumbnailEvent = settings.thumbnailActivationEvent,
                    thumbnailLinks,
                    dimBackgroundOverlay = $("." + settings.dimBackgroundOverlayClass),

                    // General image settings
                    usePreloading = settings.usePreloading,
                    useAltAsTooltip = settings.useAltAsTooltip,
                    useTextAsTooltip = settings.useTextAsTooltip,
                    images = settings.images,
                    startIndex = (settings.startIndex > 0)? (settings.startIndex - 1) : settings.startIndex,
                    imageIndex = startIndex,
                    currentImageIndex = imageIndex,
                    startSlideShowFromBeginning = settings.startSlideShowFromBeginning,
                    dimBackgroundAtLoad = settings.dimBackgroundAtLoad,

                    // General fade settings
                    useFadingIn = settings.useFadingIn,
                    useFadingOut = settings.useFadingOut,
                    useFadeWhenNotSlideshow = settings.useFadeWhenNotSlideshow,
                    useFadeForSlideshow = settings.useFadeForSlideshow,
                    useDimBackgroundForSlideshow = settings.useDimBackgroundForSlideshow,
                    loopSlideshow = settings.loopSlideshow,
                    fadeTime = settings.fadeTime,
                    timeForSlideInSlideshow = settings.timeForSlideInSlideshow,
                    startSlideshowAtLoad = settings.startSlideshowAtLoad,
                    slideshowPlaying = false,
                    timer,

                    // Sets main image
                    setImage = function () {
                        // Set main image values
                        var imageItem = images[imageIndex];
                        mainImage.attr({
                            src : imageItem.image,
                            alt : imageItem.alt
                        });

                        // If the alt text should be used as the tooltip
                        if (useAltAsTooltip) {
                            mainImage.attr("title", imageItem.alt);
                        }

                        // If the image text should be used as the tooltip
                        if (useTextAsTooltip) {
                            mainImage.attr("title", imageItem.text);
                        }

                        // Set image text
                        if (imageTextContainer.length > 0) {
                            imageTextContainer.text(imageItem.text);
                        }

                        // Set image link
                        if (imageLink.length > 0) {
                            var url = imageItem.url;
                            if (typeof url !== "undefined" && url.length > 0) {
                                imageLink.attr("href", imageItem.url);
                            }
                            else {
                                imageLink.removeAttr("href");
                            }   
                        }

                        // Set image counter values
                        if (imageCounter.length > 0) {
                            imageCounter.text((imageIndex + 1) + "/" + (images.length));
                        }

                        if (!loopSlideshow) {
                            // Enabling/disabling previous link
                            if (imageIndex === 0) {
                                previousLink.addClass("picture-slides-disabled");
                            }
                            else {
                                previousLink.removeClass("picture-slides-disabled");
                            }

                            // Enabling/disabling next link
                            if (imageIndex === (images.length - 1)) {
                                nextLink.addClass("picture-slides-disabled");
                            }
                            else {
                                nextLink.removeClass("picture-slides-disabled");
                            }
                        }

                        // Keeping a reference to the current image index
                        currentImageIndex = imageIndex;

                        // Adding/removing classes from thumbnail
                        if (thumbnailContainer[0]) {                            
                            thumbnailLinks.removeClass("picture-slides-selected-thumbnail");
                            $(thumbnailLinks[imageIndex]).addClass("picture-slides-selected-thumbnail");
                        }
                    },

                    // Navigate to previous image
                    prev = function () {
                        if (imageIndex > 0 || loopSlideshow) {
                            if (imageIndex === 0) {
                                imageIndex = (images.length -1);
                            }
                            else {
                                imageIndex = --imageIndex;
                            }
                            if (useFadingOut && (useFadeWhenNotSlideshow || slideshowPlaying) && imageIndex !== currentImageIndex) {
                                fadeContainer.stop();
                                fadeContainer.fadeTo(fadeTime, 0, function () {
                                    setImage(imageIndex);                                   
                                }); 
                            }
                            else {
                                if (useFadingIn && imageIndex !== currentImageIndex) {
                                    fadeContainer.css("opacity", "0");
                                }
                                setImage(imageIndex);
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    // Navigate to next image
                    next = function (specifiedIndex) {
                        if (imageIndex < (images.length -1) || typeof specifiedIndex !== "undefined" || loopSlideshow) {
                            if (typeof specifiedIndex !== "undefined") {
                                imageIndex = specifiedIndex;
                            }
                            else if (imageIndex === (images.length-1)) {
                                imageIndex = 0;
                            }
                            else {
                                imageIndex = ++imageIndex;
                            }
                            if (useFadingOut && (useFadeWhenNotSlideshow || slideshowPlaying) && imageIndex !== currentImageIndex) {
                                fadeContainer.stop();
                                fadeContainer.fadeTo(fadeTime, 0, function () {
                                    setImage(imageIndex);                                   
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                if (useFadingIn && imageIndex !== currentImageIndex) {
                                    fadeContainer.css("opacity", "0");
                                }   
                                setImage(imageIndex);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            stopSlideshow();
                        }
                    },

                    // Start slideshow
                    startSlideshow = function () {
                        slideshowPlaying = true;
                        startSlideShowLink.hide();
                        stopSlideShowLink.show();
                        if (startSlideShowFromBeginning) {
                            next(0);
                        }
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        timer = setTimeout(function () {
                            next();
                        }, timeForSlideInSlideshow);
                        if (useDimBackgroundForSlideshow && dimBackgroundOverlay[0]) {
                            elm.addClass("picture-slides-dimmed-background");
                            dimBackgroundOverlay.show();
                        }
                    },

                    // Stop slideshow
                    stopSlideshow = function () {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        slideshowPlaying = false;
                        startSlideShowLink.show();
                        stopSlideShowLink.hide();
                        if (useDimBackgroundForSlideshow && dimBackgroundOverlay[0]) {
                            elm.removeClass("picture-slides-dimmed-background");
                            dimBackgroundOverlay.hide();
                        }
                    };

                // Fade in/show image when it has loaded
                mainImage[0].onload = function () {
                    if (useFadingIn && (useFadeWhenNotSlideshow || slideshowPlaying)) {
                        fadeContainer.fadeTo(fadeTime, 1, function () {
                            if (slideshowPlaying) {
                                clearTimeout(timer);
                                timer = setTimeout(function () {
                                    next();
                                }, timeForSlideInSlideshow);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        fadeContainer.css("opacity", "1");
                        fadeContainer.show();
                        if (slideshowPlaying) {
                            clearTimeout(timer);
                            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                                next();
                            }, timeForSlideInSlideshow);
                        }
                    }
                    mainImageFailedToLoad.hide();
                };

                mainImage[0].onerror = function () {
                    fadeContainer.css("opacity", "1");
                    mainImageFailedToLoad.show();
                    if (slideshowPlaying) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        timer = setTimeout(function () {
                            next();
                        }, timeForSlideInSlideshow);
                    }
                };

                // Previous image click
                previousLink.click(function (evt) {
                    prev();
                    return false;
                });

                // Next image click
                nextLink.click(function (evt) {
                    next();
                    return false;
                });

                // Start slideshow click
                startSlideShowLink.click(function () {
                    startSlideshow();
                    return false;
                });

                // Stop slideshow click
                stopSlideShowLink.click(function () {
                    stopSlideshow();
                    return false;
                });

                // Shows navigation links and image counter
                previousLink.show();
                nextLink.show();
                startSlideShowLink.show();
                imageCounter.show();

                // Stop slideshow click
                stopSlideShowLink.click(function () {
                    stopSlideshow();
                });

                // Thumbnail references
                if (thumbnailContainer[0]) {
                    thumbnailLinks = $(thumbnailContainer).find("a");
                    $(thumbnailLinks[imageIndex]).addClass("picture-slides-selected-thumbnail");
                    for (var i=0, il=thumbnailLinks.length, thumbnailLink; i<il; i++) {
                        thumbnailLink = $(thumbnailLinks[i]);
                        thumbnailLink.data("linkIndex", i);
                        thumbnailLink.bind(thumbnailEvent, function (evt) {
                            next($(this).data("linkIndex"));
                            this.blur();
                            return false;
                        });
                    }
                }

                // Sets initial image
                setImage();

                // If play slideshow at load
                if (startSlideshowAtLoad) {
                    startSlideshow();
                }

                if (dimBackgroundAtLoad) {
                    elm.addClass("picture-slides-dimmed-background");
                    dimBackgroundOverlay.show();
                }

                if (usePreloading) {
                    var imagePreLoadingContainer = $("<div />").appendTo(document.body).css("display", "none");
                    for (var j=0, jl=images.length, image; j<jl; j++) {
                        $('<img src="' + images[j].image + '" alt="" />').appendTo(imagePreLoadingContainer);
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    return {
        set : set,
        init : init
    };
}();
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.PictureSlides.init();
});
```

Comment: Please include your relevant code in your question.

Comment: jquery on: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: it's probable that one script is saving a copy of the element as a variable, before it is changed, and thus you are seeing the "old source". Without any code however anything anyone will present will be shots in the dark. Either talk/email to the person who generated the plugin's or start debugging in [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx) or [chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: I emailed both authors and no reply.

Comment: after you change the src you may try reapplying the plugin to the element in question.

Comment: scrappedcola, I'm new at this so when you say "re-apply the plugin to the element in question" are you saying to code it to run the loupe plugin again? Not sure how to do that. It appears that the loupe is getting the info from the original html code.

Comment: How is the image being changed?  Can you provide that bit of code?

Comment: `$('.louped').ClassyLoupe({
    maxSize: 600,
    loupeToggleSpeed: 'fast'
});` after the code changes your html run your code that looks something like this.

Comment: @scrappedcola, thank you, I figured that much out. What I need to know is how to have the loupe script know that the image has changed. Right now it's seeing the line 

`code`<img class="picture-slides-image"  src="artifactImages/bowl_fragment_16134_04E.jpg" alt=""/ > `code`

 as the starting image, which it is, but when the gallery script changes the image, the loupe script only sees the original src. I need to know how to get the loupe script to recognize the change.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that you can easily call to apply the classy loupe plugin:

```
function addLoupe()
{
   $('.picture-slides-image').ClassyLoupe({
       maxSize: 600,
       size: 300,
       minSize: 200,
       loupeToggleSpeed: 'fast'
   });
}
```

Then in the jQuery.PictureSlides file find the section for `setImage`, as the comments in the code suggests this sets the main image. At the end of the function, before the closing `}` call the function created `addLoupe`. This should reset the classy loupe on the new image.

---- edit 
Digging through the PictureSlides code I see that there is an option to set the `thumbnailActivationEvent`. When I followed that to where it is set/used in the plugin I found where it is being bound. If you apply loupe at this point the new large image *should* be present and have the new class that you bind on `picture-slides-image`.

Try:

```
thumbnailLink.bind(thumbnailEvent, function (evt) {
   next($(this).data("linkIndex"));
   this.blur();
   addLoupe(); // reset your loupe settings here.
   return false;
});
```

If that doesn't work, I've got nothing else for you.

Comment: This looks like the same code, minus the function, that is in the HTML. But I placed it where you suggested and the loupe stopped working.

Comment: so you actually call `addLoupe()` inside the `setImage` method of the  PictureSlides file? Are you defining `addLoupe` before you bring in PictureSlides (which means you will also need to bring in ClassyLoupe before you bring in PictureSlides and also before where you define `addLoupe`? Are you getting any errors in console? (hit f12 in your browser to bring up the developer tools).

Comment: Based on your instructions I added addLoupe() here:

`code`// Sets main image 
setImage = function () {
// Set main image values
var imageItem = images[imageIndex];
mainImage.attr({
src : imageItem.image,
alt : imageItem.alt
addLoupe()
});`code`

It doesn't work. Says Syntax error.

Comment: should be added after this if block
 `// Adding/removing classes from thumbnail
                        if (thumbnailContainer[0]) {                            
                            thumbnailLinks.removeClass("picture-slides-selected-thumbnail");
                            $(thumbnailLinks[imageIndex]).addClass("picture-slides-selected-thumbnail");
                        }
                       addLoupe();
                    },//end of add`

Comment: you can't add a function call inside where the attribute is being edited. the function is the entire block starting with `setImage = function () {` and ending `},`.

Comment: I added it to your above place and no errors but the main image now disappears when the thumbnail is selected. And, the loupe image stays as the original image.